# Use Codeigniter with IP/username path

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I'm moving my site to a new server. I restored the CPanel backup but I want to test the site before I change the domain to point to the new server. Until I link the domain I would load it using the IP/username, like: http://192.169.1.100/~myusername

Of course that breaks Codeigniter when I open http://192.169.1.100/~myusername/pagename

How can I get it working with the test server until I'm ready to point the domain over?

Comment: In theory you should only need to change the base URL: [CodeIgniter 3](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/index.html) | [CodeIgniter 4](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/running.html#initial-configuration-setup)

Comment: I already sent the base_url in config.php to http://192.169.1.100/~myusername but that didn't get it working. Is that right?